# Page Index Changing do not works properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

Am using `vs-2010` with `c#`, In my application i want to clear a label text in the Page index changing Event. Here is my code

```
protected void gvDetails_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    // BindGrid(ddlJournal.SelectedItem.Text);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = ViewState["ds"] as DataSet;

    if ((Convert.ToString(ViewState["Template"]) != null 
        || (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Template"]) != "")))
    {
        if ((Convert.ToString(ViewState["Template"]) == "T1"))
        {
            GridData("T1");
        }
        else if ((Convert.ToString(ViewState["Template"]) == "T2"))
        {
            GridData("T2");
        }
        else if ((Convert.ToString(ViewState["Template"]) == "T3"))
        {
            GridData("T3");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        BindGrid(ddlJournal.SelectedItem.Text);
    }

    btnupdate_Click(sender, e);

    lblError.Text = "";
    lblSuccess.Text = "";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Key", "call()", true);
}
```

My problem is the page index are changing properly but the label values do not be empty , what is the problem in my application and how can i fix this.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code is a mess and do not say thanks here on **STACKOVERFLOW** and second of all you are calling a method is your *gvDetails_PageIndexChanging* handler that calls *btnupdate_Click(sender, e);* do you set a value for your labels there?

Comment: yes,of course am setting label values in  btnupdate_Click(sender, e);

Comment: so if your btnupdate_Click(sender,e); causes postback then the rest of your code in gvDetails_PageIndexChanging will not work.

Comment: create a new method for doing this do not call btnupdate_click for such a thing